# Apache POI: Multiple cell comments in one cell are not allowed

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to add comment to cells. The code works fine for 2 rows. But when the row number goes to third, it starts giving me the error:-

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple cell comments in one cell are not allowed

I add the comment when I detect an exception while reading from cell value. Given is the method which I use for adding the comment:-

```
private void cellException(Sheet datatypeSheet, CellStyle cellErrorStyle, Row invCurrentRow,
        int invCellNum, String mainMessage)
{

    Cell mainCell = invCurrentRow.getCell(invCellNum);

    if (ExcelUtility.checkIfCellValueAbsent(mainCell))
        mainCell = invCurrentRow.createCell(invCellNum);

    mainCell.setCellStyle(cellErrorStyle);

    Comment mainComment = mainCell.getCellComment();

    if (Util.isNullOrEmpty(mainComment))
        mainComment = datatypeSheet.createDrawingPatriarch().createCellComment(
                new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, (short) 3, 3, (short) 5, 6));
    mainComment.setString(new XSSFRichTextString(mainMessage));
    mainCell.setCellComment(mainComment);
    datatypeSheet.autoSizeColumn(mainCell.getColumnIndex());
}
```

This code works perfect for two rows. I don't understand what goes wrong with the third row.

I'm using XSSFWorkbook and following is the dependency I added in my springboot project:-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried searching for answer and I found one which I thought could be useful but it wasn't:-

[Multiple comments apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766839/multiple-comments-apache-poi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating all cell comments using the same anchor which starts on column index 3, row index 3, which is `D4`. So all your cell comments belongs to `D4`. Then, if you try creating a cell comment using that same anchor and there is already a comment in `D4`, this leads to the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple cell comments in one cell are not allowed, cell: D4
```

Do using different achors for each cell comment:

```
...
  if (mainComment == null)
   mainComment = datatypeSheet.createDrawingPatriarch().createCellComment(
                  //new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, (short) 3, 3, (short) 5, 6));
                  new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, mainCell.getColumnIndex(), mainCell.getRowIndex(), mainCell.getColumnIndex()+2, mainCell.getRowIndex()+3));
...
```

Comment: I did not notice the mistake. You are right. I later realized that I was not able to add comment to only D4 cell. Thanks a lot.